# What's in the crater on Europa in "2010: The Year We Make Contact"?

Tags: arthur-c-clarke, 2010-odyssey-two

In the film, the Russians send an unmanned probe into a crater on Europa, but before we get to see what's in it, the probe is blasted off into space, probably by whatever is in the crater. What the heck is in the crater?

Comment: *"..but what the heck is in the crater?"*  Here, there be dragons?

Comment: I cast you back to SO where you cometh from! :-), seriously , do you know?

Comment: I seriously don't.  :(

Comment: As David Bowman once said: "Whoever lands in craters should see to it that in the process he does not become a crater. And if you gaze long enough into a monolith, the monolith will gaze back into you."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The book describes this better, but obviously has a different plot to the movie.  There, the joint Russian/American team arrive in the Jupiter system to find that a Chinese ship had also arrived, which carried out a manned landing on Europa and was ultimately destroyed by a life form they found there:

> ... a huge dark mass rising up from the depths. At first we thought it was a school of fish ­ too large for a single organism - then it started to break through the ice ... like huge strands of wet seaweed, crawling along the ground ... I've seen pictures of the kelp forests off California ... Imagine an oak tree - better still, a banyan with its multiple trunks and roots - flattened out by gravity and trying to creep along the ground...

(Chapter 11 - Ice and Vacuum)

In the movie of course none of this happens; according to the [Wikipedia summary of the plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_%28film%29) (apologies but I haven't watched the movie in some time) the explanation is:

> Though the Soviet crew believes the burst was simply electromagnetic radiation, Floyd suspects that it was actually a warning to stay away from Europa.

The most obvious explanation is that it actually *was* a warning to keep away, coming from the Monolith; that's consistent with the warning given at the end of both the movie and the book:

> ALL THESE WORLDS ARE YOURS - EXCEPT EUROPA.
> ATTEMPT NO LANDINGS THERE.

So the probe wasn't actually blasted out by something in the crater, but ejected by some power of the Monolith in order to ensure no interference with its own plans for furthering the evolution of life on Europa.